# executing javascript inside href attribute of anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I checked a lot on Hrefs but couldn't get something related.

I am trying to do this in code behind which is actually a custom control class

```
writer.Write("<a href='javascript:document.location.href?" + filter.ParameterName + "=" + filter.QueryValue + "'>" + filter.UserVisibleValue + "</a>|&nbsp;");
```

now this gets me something like this on hover of above anchor 'document.location.href?Test one=2013' and when i click it, this throws an obvious javascript error 'SyntaxError: missing : in conditional expression' because it takes it as a conditional operator and hence finds : missing.

I simply want that document.location.href (current url) should be calculated and the value put in where i use it.

I know that i may simply call a javascript function and inside that function i set the href but can i do it this way?

Comment: Apart from if it's possible or not; Why would you want it? Just use a function. It looks and reads a lot more comfortable than inline crap!

Comment: That is not how it works. When you use "javascript:" as a prefix for the value of href, everything that follows is treated as javascript code and gets executed. What you want is to use the same URL as of the current page as the base + some query string. Right?

Comment: yes but these are a number of anchors generated in a foreach loop and each anchor will have different query string created dynamically inside the control class

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
writer.Write("<a href='javascript:window.location = document.location.href?" + filter.ParameterName + "=" + filter.QueryValue + "'>" + filter.UserVisibleValue + "</a>|&nbsp;");
```

Note that you might have to escape values as needed otherwise JavaScript will become invalid. To prove that above approach works, you can copy-paste following simpler example in any HTML page and see it working:

```
<a href="javascript:window.location=window.location + '?a=5'">bla</a>
```

Comment: I would suggest first try out 2nd example in the answer which is very simple. You can put that in HTML and see it working. That atleast would prove that basic concept works. Then see what is the value you are generating in href dynamically. Very likely you are not escaping some characters and so JavaScript is becoming invalid. To debug this, I would highly recommend put above basic code in function and then use Chrome dev tools to set breakpoint in there.